# How to create a half sliding ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

How I can create a half sliding window (from right to left) that shows above the last clicked view as in the Airbnb application?
[image: Air bnb app[1]]

Currently there is what I have:
[image]

When I click on the Profile tab I want to show such a view that is above the last one clicked.

Here is how my Storyboard looks like:

[image]

Is there any native way I can implement this?
There are a lot of applications that are using that approach but I could not see any easy way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this:

[SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift)

It is quite easy to implement and also works nicely.